# Ошибка в применении своей миграции

Tags: python, django

Создал свою миграцию. Там делаю открытие файла и заполняю бд.

Но выдает такую ошибку

```
django.db.transaction.TransactionManagementError: 
An error occurred in the current transaction. 
You can't execute queries until the end of the 'atomic' block.
```

Если закомментировать бОльшую часть кода (в основном работа с открытыми файлами), то все проходит нормально. Что это за атомарный блок и как с ним справиться?

Comment: Посмотрите решение тут https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/5859

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего проблема в обработке исключений
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/transactions/#controlling-transactions-explicitly

> Avoid catching exceptions inside atomic!
>
> When exiting an atomic block, Django looks at whether it’s exited
> normally or with an exception to determine whether to commit or roll
> back. If you catch and handle exceptions inside an atomic block, you
> may hide from Django the fact that a problem has happened. This can
> result in unexpected behavior.